# Google Sign-in: Should I store and refresh tokens even if I don't use them?

Tags: authentication, google-oauth, google-signin, access-token, refresh-token

I'm implementing a `Log in with Google` feature for my system and I'm wondering if it's necessary to periodically store and refresh the tokens, even when they are not actively used to consume any of Google's services.

Currently, I have my own authentication flow supporting the `username/password` method only. Upon user login, the system issue 2 tokens: the first is a JWT `Access Token` used to validate each request, and the second is a plain `Refresh Token` stored in my database, used to generate a new `Access Token` when needed.

If a user opts for the `Google Sign-in` method, I plan to ask them to complete Google's authentication flow so that they can send me the authorization code. I would then exchange it for Google's account information and associate its ID with the corresponding account in my system. Subsequently, both Google tokens would be discarded, and the session would be managed by my system, issuing and validating it's own tokens.

The problem with this approach is that the user could revoke access for my application in their Google account, and it would have no effect on my system.This is because I'm not checking the expiration of `Google's Access Token` nor using `Google's Refresh Token` to generate a new one.

Should I consider storing and revalidating these tokens, even if I don't use them for any other purpose, as a good practice?

If revalidation is desired, I'm thinking of doing it under the hood each time the client runs my currently implemented `Refresh Token` flow. I would refresh both tokens, expanding their lifespans. If Google's revalidation fails, then my own `Refresh Token` is invalidated as well. Additionally, I might store the last `Google's Access Token` just in case I want to implement an integration with any Google's service in the future.

Your insights on this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Sign in doesnt have refresh tokens it has id token.   Authorization has access tokens and refresht okens and yes you should store them so your application can access the users data when they are not online

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo This is the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect) i'm following. The three of them (`id_token`, `access_token` and `refresh_token`) are issued after registration. `id_token` and `access_token` are JWT tokens that expire after an hour. The only way of validating if the user hasn't revoke access for my app is using `refresh_token` to generate a new `access_token`. My question is: should I do it periodically even if I'm not using them just to check revoked access?